# How do I make the LM3914 (LED) Bar-graph driver IC make the LEDs light up brighter?

Tags: led, display, led-driver, led-matrix, lm3915

Like I said in the title, I am using the LM3914 IC to drive a 10 segment LED Bar-graph. The actual subsystem has the signal pin on the IC connected to a capacitor, thus displays the amount of charge the capacitor is holding on the Bar-graph.

I've done a test of my entire circuit on a breadboard and found that every subsystem - including the bar-graph circuit - worked a treat.

However, the LED segments on the Bar-graph are so dim that they are barely visible under bright light. Is there a way of making the 3914 increase the current through the LED segments to make them brighter?

Here is a rough schematic of the circuit I am using:
[image]

(Supply and resistor values are actual)

Any pointers would be extremely helpful thanks!

Here is the specific bar-graph if it is of use:
https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/spec/DC10GWA.pdf

Answer (score 6):

From the datasheet:

> The current drawn out of the reference voltage pin (pin 7) determines LED current. Approximately 10 times this current will be drawn through each lighted LED ...

Since the voltage is 1.25V, the current in the schematic will be:

\$ {12.5\text{V} \over {1\text{k}\Omega+3.9\text{k}\Omega}} \approx 2.55mA\$

Reduce the resistances in the divider to about 1/8 of their current values.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't spot that in the data sheet at all XD

Comment: Thanks mate, I replaced it with a 100 ohm and a 390 ohm and it worked superbly!

Comment: @tonyg. At 1/10 the divider, your putting 25.5 mA through each led which is above the normal 20mA limit for normal life of the led. Also, your putting another 25 mA through the divider, which may be bad for battery life, if battery powered.

Comment: Well no, the divider gets 1/10 of the LED current, so 2.55mA.